# How can I redirect the user to a servlet instead of an index file on initial page load?

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, servlets, webserver

Here is what I have configured in web.xml :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But if I change it to a servlet :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>myservlet</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I receive a 404 error message.

How can I redirect the user to a servlet instead of an index file on initial page load ?

THe servlet is based on Spring :

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="redirect")
    public String displaySearch(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("test" , "test");

        return "mypage";
    }

}
```

I just need the "redirect" servlet to be invoked by default.

Edit : the spring dispatcher servlet is mapped on the '/' url pattern, is this incorrect also ?

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via a servlet mapping, e.g.:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: but how do I instruct the application to load this servlet as its initial page instead of "index.jsp" as configured in original question ?

Comment: Exactly as written. When you open `http://yoursite/`, the `myservlet` will handle the request (responding with whatever you programmed it to respond with, instead of the contents of index.jsp).

Comment: thanks, please see question edit. That will not work for me in this case since its a spring servlet ?

Comment: Could you add another method e.g. `public String rootHandler(Model model)`, annotated with `@RequestMapping(value="/")` and calling your `displaySearch` method?

Comment: This is a bad recommendation. This servlet would take over all the job of the container's builtin default servlet, including serving static resources like CSS/JS/images!